# Is there a build in TwoWay Stream

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have a webapi (asp.net core) that receive a file and post to another webAPI

for now, I create a `FileStream`  , and using HttpClient to Post this file.

But I wonder is that a two way Stream that can replace the `FileStream`, I mean a Stream that's `ReadAsync` will wait until it have enough bytes for read's buffer.

```
var content = new MultipartFormDataContent(); 
// the problem is here, the stream must be ready for "read to end", 
// so I buffered the uploaded file to a FileStream
content.Add(new StreamContent(filestream),"file1","myfilename");
await client.PostAsync("url",content )
```

Comment: I'm not really understanding the scenario you're describing. Can you elaborate, and maybe demonstrate your current method?

Comment: @John I add some code hope that will help you to understand

Comment: So you mean you want a stream that you can write into, and then as you write into it it will send it with `HttpClient`?

Comment: yes,   write: 100bytes |  read:80 bytes (ok) , read:80 bytes(wait) | write:30 bytes, write finish  |  previous read complate with 50 bytes, It's like the `PipeReader` and `PipeWriter`